# How to account for mediators in ANOVA?

Tags: anova, manova, mediation

So I have two **IVs** (customization, purchase type), three **mediators** (self-expressiveness, social connections, evoked comparisons) and one DV (happiness). **Purchase type** is either experiential or material, and customization is either standard or customized.

I would like to show two things:

*1) That those three mediators exist for both relationships between IV and DV:*

customization -> self-expressiveness, social connections, evoked comparisons -> happiness

purchase type -> self-expressiveness, social connections, evoked comparisons -> happiness

*2) That the DV (happiness) will be the highest for a specific combination of IVs, namely customized material purchases.*

I wanted to test 2) by running a simple two-way ANOVA, but this would be wrong given that the relationship is mediated right?

Would it be possible to run two ANOVAs (one with and one without the mediators) and then compare the effect sizes? If yes, how would I "add" the mediators to my model?
Or would it be possible to run a MANOVA with happiness and the mediators as DVs?

Comment: You can not do mediation with anova directly, except if you use the Baron and Kenny approach, which I would not recommend. What software are you using?